# Soundcloud custom player supports cloudfront streaming?

Tags: python-2.7, avaudioplayer, cdn, soundcloud, amazon-cloudfront

If the soundcloud custom player supports only soundcloud flash streaming or we can use anyother thirdparty streaming servers like cloudfront ,CDNetworks,Akamai,Edgecast,Limelight etc...?

Comment: Add more information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. You should a JS Audio library for that, such SoundManager 2, Audio5JS etc.